# Bash print command that will be run

Tags: bash, variables, variable-expansion

I have a bash script where I'm setting a variable via `cmd$(somestuff goes $here)`
on my next line I echo that `echo "$cmd"`which gives me the output but how do I get just the params that we set for the command so I know what was actually executed?

Something like printf "$cmd" where it would be "somestuff goes poof"

Comment: You may be interested in using `set -x` to trace your commands. You can either put `set -x` in your script, or run your script with `bash -x ./script.sh`. Read more about shell options here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin

Comment: `cmd="somestuff goes $here"`; `echo $cmd`; to execute `$cmd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a variable called `cmd` that would do `some stuff` you should define it like this:

```
cmd="somestuff goes here"
```

With `cmd$(somestuff goes $here)` what your shell is doing is trying to run `something` (still not defined, that you called `cmd`) followed by `$(something else to run)`.

So, if you also want to print what is your script going to run, just follow this order:

```
# define your variable
cmd="something goes here"

# print what is going to run
printf "$cmd"

# then run it
$cmd
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach. Storing a command in a variable will fail if there's any nontrivial shell syntax in the command (quotes, escapes, pipes/redirects, ...) (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")[http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050], and is generally not a good idea. Variables should be used for storing data, not executable code. Also, using `echo` on an unquoted variable has its own set of possible problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson whats your better solution as an answer?

Comment: @Tony It really depends on the exact situation and goal. `set -x` is the standard way to get the shell itself to print equivalent commands to what it's executing. BashFAQ 50 (sorry about the botched link) has some [other options](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I_want_a_log_of_my_script.27s_actions). To give more specific recommendations, I'd really need to see the actual code involved.